# Justice League comic where the Arkham Asylum gate is locked with a Kryptonite chain

Tags: story-identification, dc, justice-league

A while ago I read part of a comic storyline on Imgur and can't remember which issue this was. It seemed to me something out of a more recent Justice League comic but a) I'm not that familiar with DC and b) maybe I am wrong about the art style but it reminded me with late 90's X-Men art.

What I remember is as follows: Batman is standing at the gate of Arkham Asylum (on the inside of the compound) while Superman, Wonder Woman and Flash are on the other side of the gate. For some reason they want to enter Arkham but Batman won't let them. Superman then tries to shatter the chain with a heat ray but the chain pulverizes into Kryptonite and Batman is kinda smug and says to Flash and Wonder Woman that Superman isn't the only one for which he has this kind of plan.

Comment: It would be better if you could (if possible) add the imgur image that you saw. Can make the search really easy and quick then.

Comment: Yeah I know but I haven't been able to find it again. Otherwise I would have added it

Comment: @Noosrep Could you check the current answer? It describes a similar scene but no Kryptonite or chains involved. If it helps [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAX7N.jpg) is a relevant image.

Comment: Are you sure this was an official DC comic, or is it possible you were looking at a fan comics which was good enough to make you think it was official?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The Kryptonite chain is something I clearly remember, the rest is a little bit hazy so I'm indeed wondering if I'm mixing some things

Comment: @Jenayah Could be, I'm not at all familiar with DC and just came across the pages at random

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure this is the [*Injustice: Gods Among Us*](http://Injustice%20gods%20among%20us) comic series, although I can't remember the exact issue.

In the series, Joker managed to get Lois Lane killed and Metropolis annihilated. This leads to Superman becoming a tyrant, and splitting the superheroes. On one side, there are heroes who agree with Superman, that the only way for humanity to stop crime is to have an absolute leader (i.e. himself). Wonder Woman as well as Flash both belong to this group.

At some point Superman's group decided to go to Arkham Asylum, in order to execute the criminals in there.

But Batman, who disagrees with Superman, is there to stop them.

Comment: It isn't the Injustice series because of several reasons: (1) Joker is locked up in Gotham Prison and not Arkham. (2) Batman is inside the cell with Joker when Superman blasts through the wall. (3) Superman is alone; no one else is with him as the OP mentions. (4) the art in Injustice isn't what the OP says; it ain't like the 90s X-men art (5) Most importantly, kryptonite isn't involved in this scene. 

Thus, the DV

Comment: @Shreedhar There is a standoff between Batman and the other Justice League members in the series. However, Batman only shocks Cyborg, there is nothing to do with Kryptonite or even chains and the scene doesn't really play out as the OP remembers. It is possible this is correct and the OP was wildly mistaken though.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot yeah you're right. I hardly saw any similarities in the OP and this answer (except Superman and Batman's confrontation). So, quoting Obi-Wan, *this isn't the answer you're looking for* :p I may be wrong though and the OP might've gotten some stuff mixed up, idk.

Comment: @Shreedhar Yep, I should have checked before posting, after checking the Arkham Asylum scene, it's probably not Injustice